# Can I set routes by resource method with exclusions in Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

[Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) says that I can write

```rb
resources :photos
```

in `routes.rb`.
That will create routes:

```
HTTP Verb   Path                Controller#Action   Used for
GET         /photos             photos#index        display a list of all photos
GET         /photos/new         photos#new          return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST        /photos             photos#create       create a new photo
GET         /photos/:id         photos#show         display a specific photo
GET         /photos/:id/edit    photos#edit         return an HTML form for editing a photo
PATCH/PUT   /photos/:id         photos#update       update a specific photo
DELETE      /photos/:id         photos#destroy      delete a specific photo
```

Can I write something like

```rb
resources :photos, :exclude => [:edit, :update]
```

to get all routes except `edit` and `update`:

```
GET         /photos             photos#index    display a list of all photos
GET         /photos/new         photos#new      return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST        /photos             photos#create   create a new photo
GET         /photos/:id         photos#show     display a specific photo
DELETE      /photos/:id         photos#destroy  delete a specific photo
```

or I can only write every route manually for expected result?

Comment: In addition to the three answers that will undoubtedly be here once I finished writing this, I recommend you read through the [Rails Routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), which is a good introduction on the topic (as are the other guides, by the way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can do something like:

```
resources :photos, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show, :destroy]
```

Or if you prefer:

```
resources :photos, except: [:edit, :update]
```

Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

The `:except` option specifies a route or list of routes that Rails should not create:

```
resources :photos, except: [:edit, :update]
```

for more info check here
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html